# How to print access log without spring?

Tags: java, logging, aop

What I really want is AOP, which is supported in spring. But sadly my leader didn't allow us to use spring. We write a service layer with java, thrift and jdbc. I used to use spring's aspect to print the access logs in every `action`. So I don't know how to do this now. I tried a plugin named `jcabi-aspect` but it didn't work. And also I didn't figure it out.
So I wanna know if there is some thing can help me to do this.

Comment: using `Filter` http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html  create your own interceptor to do access logging, or utilize the mechanisms provided by your application server, for example, you can use `Valve` for access logging in `Tomcat`.

Comment: The *Spring* code is available, what you need is just study the code to understand how it works. The behaviour beneath *String* is far away to be simple, and I think you should follow a differen path if you're not allowed to use the *Spring* library. That's because it is much safer to use a robust library rather than write your own, for bugs you could have. Expecially if you don't know how to do it.

Comment: What exactly didn't work with jcabi-aspects? Submit a separate questions, I'll try to help (I'm one of its developers)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [AspectJ](https://eclipse.org/aspectj/) which is

- more powerful than the small AspectJ language subset implemented in Spring AOP,
- faster and more resource-efficient because it does not need/use dynamic proxies,
- useable in any Java SE application without any frameworks like Spring or Java EE.

Extensive documentation can be found [here](https://eclipse.org/aspectj/docs.php).

Now the remaining question is whether your leader will grant you permission to use AspectJ. ;-)